# Check, Nothing is changed in Model values MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, object, post, model

I've a Model like following:

```
public class Page
{
     private readonly IndianTime _g = new IndianTime();

     public Page()
     {
         CreatedOn = _g.DateTime;
         Properties = "Published";
         Tags = "Page";
         RelativeUrl = string.Empty;
     }

     public string Path
     {
         get { return (ParentPage != null) ? ParentPage.Heading + " >> " + Heading : Heading; }
     }

     [Key]
     public int Id { get; set; }

     [StringLength(200), Required, DataType(DataType.Text)]
     public string Title { get; set; }

     [StringLength(200), Required, DataType(DataType.Text)]
     public string Heading { get; set; }

     [MaxLength, Required, DataType(DataType.Html)]
     public string Content { get; set; }

     [Display(Name = "Reference Code"), ScaffoldColumn(false)]
     public string ReferenceCode { get; set; }

     [Required]
     [Remote("CheckDuplicate", "Page", ErrorMessage = "Url has already taken", AdditionalFields = "initialUrl")]
     public string Url { get; set; }

     [Display(Name = "Created On"), ScaffoldColumn(false)]
     public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }

     //Parent Page Object (Self Reference: ParentId = > Id)
     [Display(Name = "Parent Page")]
     public int? ParentId { get; set; }

     [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "Root")]
     public virtual Page ParentPage { get; set; }

     public virtual ICollection<Page> ChildPages { get; set; }
}
```

During Update, is there any to check Model values are "Changed" or "Nothing  has changed" after `POST` method?

Say for example: (See the commented lines)

```
[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(WebPage webpage)
{
   try
   {
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
          // If (webpage object values are unchanged, submitted as it is
          // {
          //    Do not insert any values into Another Table
          // }
          // else
          // {
          //    Inert into another table
          // }
          _db.Entry(webpage).State = EntityState.Modified;
          _db.SaveChanges();
          return RedirectToAction("Index");
      }
   }
   catch (DataException)
   {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCode.Msg.ContactSystemAdmin.ToString());
   }
   return View(webpage);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
[HttpPost, ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(WebPage webpage)
{
   try
   {
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
          var dbEntry=_db.GetEntryById(webpage.Id);
           //check here if properties in webPage and column values in dbEntry are 
           //same then decide whether to insert in another table or not

          _db.Entry(webpage).State = EntityState.Modified;
          _db.SaveChanges();
          return RedirectToAction("Index");
      }
   }
   catch (DataException)
   {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCode.Msg.ContactSystemAdmin.ToString());
   }
   return View(webpage);
}
```

Or Not Sure if this works

Try using `$(form).serialize()` at client side

[CHECK THIS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zFhQB/53/)

Comment: Yes, I'm doing like that only, But My question is, Is there any alternative approaches to this? say Model comparison kind of. Because in this approach, I've to compare each attribute.

Comment: I think it would be better if you check at client side using jquery by storing old values in variables and check with new variables